# React native - performance when rendering thousands of components

Tags: android, performance, react-native, svg

I'm building an app that requires about four thousand dots to be rendered. In Android studio, I'm lucky if it even renders -- usually it crashes, but when it does render it takes over ten seconds to show up. My render method is very small. It's just a View containing a function that returns the array of dots (each consists of two more nested Views).

Am I going about this the wrong way? Should I be using an SVG library instead?

If anyone is curious, it's a "life calendar" -- every dot represents a week and the plan is to dynamically color them for different events, decades, etc. Weeks might end up being be too much content for phone screens, but even when I try months the rendering delay is unbearable.

Comment: Sounds like you're using the wrong technology. If you're drawing 4000 dots, use canvas.

Comment: How are you rendering the "dots"?